How to implement i18n in Electron using electron-vite, React, and TypeScript (including Main Process)?
I'm developing an Electron application using electron-vite, React, and TypeScript. I want to implement internationalization (i18n) throughout the app, including both the renderer process (React components) and the main process. However, I'm facing challenges, particularly with implementing i18n in the main process.
My tech stack includes:

Electron

electron-vite

React

I18next

React-I18next

TypeScript


I've searched for documentation and resources on implementing i18n in this specific setup, but I haven't found any comprehensive guides or examples that address my needs, especially for the main process.
So far, I've looked into various i18n libraries commonly used with React applications, such as react-i18next or react-intl. However, these solutions primarily focus on the renderer process (React components), and I'm unsure how to extend this to the main process in Electron.
I expected to find:

A clear guide on setting up i18n for both the main and renderer processes in an Electron app.

Examples of how to use i18n functions or methods in the main process TypeScript files.

Best practices for managing translations across the entire Electron application, considering the electron-vite build process.


I would appreciate any guidance, examples, or resources that can help me implement a comprehensive i18n solution for my Electron application, with a particular focus on handling translations in the main process.

You can find most of the answers on i18next docs. Your question needs more focus.
